# jQuery: Get next table cell vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I use jQuery to access the cell (`td`) immediately *below* a given cell in a traditional grid-layout html `table` (i.e., one in which all cells span exactly one row and column)?

I know that the following will set `nextCell` to the cell to the immediate right of the clicked cell because they are immediate siblings, but I am trying to retrieve the cell immediately below the clicked cell:

```
$('td').click(function () {
    var nextCell = $(this).next('td');
});
```

Preferably I would like to do it without any use of classes or ids.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("td").click(function(){
  // cache $(this);
  var $this = $(this);

  // First, get the index of the td.
  var cellIndex = $this.index();

  // next, get the cell in the next row that has
  // the same index.
  $this.closest('tr').next().children().eq(cellIndex).doSomething();
});
```

Comment: You don't need the `'td'` argument to children, and might throw it off if the OP has [`th` elements](http://jsfiddle.net/nX7JP/) in the table.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('td').click(function () {
  var index = $(this).prevAll().length
  var cellBelow = $(this).parent().next('tr').children('td:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')')
});
```

`index` is the 0-based index of the cell in the current row (`prevAll` finds all the cells before this one).

Then in the next row, we find the `nth-child` td at index + 1 (`nth-child` starts at 1, hence the `+ 1`).

Comment: Why `$(this).prevAll().length` over `$this.index()`?

Comment: @JustinSatyr I didn't know about `index` until now. :)

Comment: I never thought about using .prevAll().length. haha. Same result, I have no idea which one is faster.

Comment: @KevinB: I would assume `index` is faster because with `.prevAll()`, it would have to compile a list of all previous elements to process.

Comment: @JustinSatyr I fixed the `index + 1`. Also, maybe `index` calls the same thing `prevAll` does so I would think they are very similar in terms of performance, `index` is easier to understand though.

Comment: @JustinSatyr Actually, that is the exact syntax that jquery uses in the core for the `$.fn.index()` method. using `prevAll` may be faster with several hundred thousand iterations, but in the end `.index()` is easier to read/maintain.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$('td').click(function () {
    var nextCell = $(this).parent().next().find("td:nth-child(whatever)");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it without using selectors, you can do:

```
    function getNextCellVertically(htmlCell){
        //find position of this cell..
        var $row = $(htmlCell).parent();
        var cellIndex = $.inArray(htmlCell, $row[0].cells);
        var table = $row.parent()[0];
        var rowIndex = $.inArray($row[0], table.rows);

        //get the next cell vertically..
        return (rowIndex < table.rows.length-1) ? 
                table.rows[rowIndex+1].cells[cellIndex] : undefined;
    }

    $('td').click(function () {
        var nextCell = getNextCellVertically(htmlCell);
        //...
    });
```

Not that efficiency is important here but it works out much faster to do it like this - in tests over 100,000 iterations it was 2-5 times faster than the selector based approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Are there an equal number of cells in each table row? If so, you could get the "count" of the cell in question, then select the corresponding cell in the `next('tr')`.